# Is it natural to say “Joe had not been throwing fishing net for long time when he found a big school of yellow fin tuna swam his way”?

Tags: grammar

Is it natural to say

> "Joe had not been throwing fishing net for long time when he found a big school of yellow fin tuna swam his way”?

Is the use of past perfect progressive tense here correct? Is it possible to use “for a long time” and when clause together?

Comment: No, it isn't natural. 'He hadn't been [fishing] _for long_ when [or before] [something happened]. Oddly enough, though, you _could_ say 'He had been fishing for a long time when...'

Comment: That’s very useful. Thank you so much!